# How to store Android benchmark results in a file?

Tags: android

I'm running benchmark tests on our Android phone. The benchmark tests include GLBenchmark, Linpack,Quadrant and Caffeine.
How do i store the results of these benchmarks into a file. Is there any way?

thanks,
Swamy

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences cartPref = getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", 0);//mode 0 means private
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = cartPref.edit();//create editor

editor.putInt("key_name", value);
editor.commit();//save the data
//to get the data
cartPref.getInt("key", -1); //-1 is the default value returned if nothing with the key "key" is found
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mihai. But i'm not looking at coding. Just want to press some buttons and it should store the results. Like "Control+S", which saves in a notepad of windows OS. Thanks. Any help will be of great help.